# RAD - How to add username token for JAX-WS in websphere application server admin console

Tags: java, web-services, security, soap

I have created a web service using JAX-WS and trying to add Simple UsernameToken security to the web service. The application is deployed on Websphere 8.5.

I found the following link which helps to add the usernameToken from ***RAD -> Services tab*** quite easily for JAX-RPC based web services but the same feature is not available for **JAX-WS** type web services.

[RAD - How to add username token for JAX RPC in websphere application server admin console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319411/rad-how-to-add-username-token-for-jax-rpc-in-websphere-application-server-admi)

Can anybody help to provide some similar kind of steps or another possible simple solution to achieve the same for JAX-WS web services?

```
    <Soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv: mustUnderstand="1"
        xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wsswssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>user</wsse: Username>
            <wsse:Password
                Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wssusername-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">paas</wsse: Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have managed to find a workaround for the problem above. Its as follows:

After googling a lot I came across a concept of ***Web-service Handler*** which can be invoked for every request and response that is either received or sent from the Webservice Provider respectively.

How to configure:
1. Create a Java File SecurityHandler and paste the following code in it:

```
public class SecurityHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>
{
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context)
    {
        boolean outbound = (Boolean)context.get(SOAPMessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        if(outbound) {
            //logic to handle a response
        }

        if (!outbound) {
            //logic to handle a request
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) {}

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }

}
```

2. Create an XML file with below code sample:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <javaee:handler-chains 
        xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <javaee:handler-chain>
       <javaee:handler>
         <javaee:handler-class>your.package.path.SecurityHandler</javaee:handler-class>
       </javaee:handler>
     </javaee:handler-chain>
   </javaee:handler-chains>`
3. To activate the handler on each request or response to the web service you exposed add the annotation in your web service class as follows:

```
    @HandlerChain(file="/your/package/path/handler-chain.xml") 
    public class my web services {
        //methods or web-services to be exposed.
    }
```